# Problem in communication of three threads in C language (deadlock occurs)

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, deadlock

I am creating a program in which i have 3 linked lists and I am trying to update or remove the nodes from these linked lists in these three threads. But the deadlock is occurring

The insertion and deletion is working fine. Here the three variables var1InUse,var2InUse and var3InUse are indicating that whether the 3 linked lists are in use or not(Not all three are use in the all threads). I am putting the threads on waiting based on var1InUse,var2InUse and var3InUse as you can see in the code. Sometimes this works fine but sometimes deadlock happens. I have searched for the solution on the internet but could find it.
Am I using the wait and signal methods correctly?

```
    pthread variables declaration

    pthread_mutex_t myMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

     pthread_cond_t t1cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

     pthread_cond_t t2cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;  

     pthread_cond_t t3cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

    int var1InUse=0,var2InUse=0,var3InUse=0;
```

THREAD 1

```
    void* thread1(void* args){
        while(var1InUse || var2InUse ) {
                pthread_cond_wait(&t1cond,&myMutex);}
        var1InUse=1,var2InUse=1;
        while(1){

                pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
                /*
                some other code about adding and removing from                         
                       linkedlist
                */
        var1InUse=0,var2InUse=0;
        pthread_cond_signal(&t2cond);
        pthread_cond_signal(&t3cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);}
     }
```

THREAD 2

```
    void* thread2(void* args){
        while(var1InUse || var2InUse || var3InUse) {
                pthread_cond_wait(&t2cond,&myMutex);}
        var1InUse=1,var2InUse=1,var3InUse=1;
        while(1){

                pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
                /*
                some other code adding and removing from linkedlist
                */
                var1InUse=0,var2InUse=0,var3InUse=0;
                pthread_cond_signal(&t1cond);
                pthread_cond_signal(&t3cond);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);}
                    }
```

THREAD 3

```
     void* thread3(void* args){
        while(var1InUse || var3InUse ) {
                pthread_cond_wait(&t3cond,&myMutex);}
        var1InUse=1,var3InUse=1;
        while(1){

                pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
                /*
                some other code adding and removing from linkedlist
                */
        var1InUse=0,var3InUse=0;
        pthread_cond_signal(&t1cond);
        pthread_cond_signal(&t2cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);}
            }
```

MAIN METHOD

```
    int main(){
        pthread_t t1,t2,t3,t4;
        pthread_mutex_init(&myMutex,0);
        pthread_create(&t1,NULL,thread1,NULL);
        pthread_create(&t2,NULL,thread2,NULL);
        pthread_create(&t3,NULL,thread3,NULL);
        pthread_join(t1,NULL); 
        pthread_join(t2,NULL);
            pthread_join(t3,NULL);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&myMutex);
        return 0
            }
```

I want the deadlock to be removed.

Comment: I think you have a copy/paste error: `pthread_cond_wait(&t1cond,&myMutex)` You're waiting on the same condition variable in all thread functions.

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly if you adopted an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and apply it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it.

Comment: @hager Yes I corrected it

Comment: @tadman You are right. Actually I posted in a hurry.

Comment: You figured out the solution ?

Comment: You need to acquire the mutex before calling `pthread_cond_wait()`. `pthread_cond_wait()` will release the mutex and acquire it again before it returns successfully.

Comment: @IanAbbott I am sorry I am new to multithreading. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mutex used by `pthread_cond_wait()` needs to locked before the function is called. Here is an extract from the man page:

> The `pthread_cond_timedwait()` and `pthread_cond_wait()` functions shall block  on a condition variable. The application shall ensure that these functions are called with mutex locked by the  calling  thread; otherwise, an error (for PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK and robust mutexes) or undefined behavior (for other mutexes) results.

Although `pthread_cond_wait()` unlocks the mutex internally, it is locked again before the function returns successfully:

> Upon successful return, the mutex shall have been locked and shall be        owned by the calling thread.

Additionally, you should access the shared variables `var1InUse`, `var2InUse` and `var3InUse` with the mutex locked.

Here is a modified version of your `thread1()` that follows these rules. The modifications to the other thread start routines should be similar:

```
void* thread1(void* args){

    pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);

    while(var1InUse || var2InUse ) {
         pthread_cond_wait(&t1cond,&myMutex);
    }
    var1InUse=1,var2InUse=1;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);

    while(1){

        pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
        /*
        some other code about adding and removing from linkedlist
        */
        var1InUse=0,var2InUse=0;
        pthread_cond_signal(&t2cond);
        pthread_cond_signal(&t3cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

(I'm not entirely sure that the above is correct, because it's not entirely clear from the original code what the `while(1)` loop is supposed to do.)

Comment: I have tried it. Now the deadlock is not occurring that frequently but still it occurs. I am adding and removing Items from the linked lists in the while loop.

Comment: @TahaKZed Perhaps the structure of the thread functions is wrong. To me, it looks strange that the only place that waits for the thread's condition variable (e.g. `t1cond`) to be set is _before_ the infinite `while (1)` loop, but the other condition variables (e.g. `t2cond` and `t3cond`) are signalled _inside_ the infinite `while (1)` loop.

Comment: Yeah. I got it! Thanks!